# css on hover text display image

Tags: jquery, css, image, text, hover

```
<style>
img { height: 100px; width: 100px; }
.hover img { display:none; }
.hover:hover img { display:block; }
</style>

<p>other text
</p>
<h1 class="hover">Test 1
<img src="ghost.jpg"/></h1>
<p>other text 
</p>
```

when i hover now it moves all the other text to display the image but i want the image to hover over the text and anything else on the page. not move the text to make room for the image. I know how to use jquery, and javascript but i didn't know what to use in this situation.

Comment: Have you tried setting your z-index on the image as well? That might solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position image absolutely without any top/bottom values:

```css
img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.hover img {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
}
.hover:hover img {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<p>other text</p>
<h1 class="hover">Test 1
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</h1>
<p>other text</p>
```

Comment: thank you that's exactly what i needed! i just over thought it way to much lolz

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of your question.

```
<style>
img { height: 100px; width: 100px; }
.hover img { display:none; }
.hover:hover img { display:block; }
</style>

<p>other text</p>
<h1 class="hover">Test 1
<img src="ghost.jpg"/></h1>
<p>other text 
</p>
```

[See demo on JSDIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/krket15x/)